# Adding numbers in succession

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby and I came across a problem online where I need to create something similar to this :

```
add(1)         # => 1
add(1).(2)     # => 3
add(1).(2).(3) # => 6
```

and so on.

I've read around and the closest I can get to having this work is with the following code :

```
def add(n)
  Proc.new { |s| s + n }
end
```

Which works to an extent.

I can run the following :

```
add(1)     # => #<Proc:0x007fb8aac309f0@(pry):2>
# or
add(1).(2) # => 3
```

But the moment I try doing this :

```
add(1).(2).(3)
```

I get the following error :

> `NoMethodError`: undefined method `call` for 3:`Integer`

Why am I getting this error and how would I change this method so that it will accept as many new values as I give it to add itself without giving me an error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? How are these numbers represented?   If you can represent the input as an array, you could use something like `[1,2,3].reduce(0, :+)`.

Comment: I'm with Marko here. If you're learning Ruby then you should learn how Ruby approaches problems like this, not invent some kind of anti-Ruby method that you prefer from a style perspective.

Comment: Your `add(1)` doesn't return `1`, but a proc object.

Comment: This looks a bit like the Builder pattern, in which a series of method calls can be chained together. The trick of it is that the method calls should do whatever they need to do, then return `self`. This means the next method in the chain is sent to the correct class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, this problem comes from CodeWars ["A Chain Adding Function"](https://www.codewars.com/kata/539a0e4d85e3425cb0000a88).

The easiest way to achieve this is to define `Integer#call`:

```
class Integer
  def call(n)
    self + n
  end
end

def add(n)
  n
end

puts add(1)
# 1
puts add(1).(2)
# 3
puts add(1).(2).(3)
# 6
```

The returned objects are plain Ruby Integers, not Proxy objects.

Note that it's probably not a good idea to modify such an important class. It's possible to use [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) in order to avoid breaking other Ruby parts:

```
module ChainAdding
  refine Integer do
    def call(n)
      self + n
    end
  end
end

def add(n)
  n
end

using ChainAdding

puts add(1)
# 1
puts add(1).(2)
# 3
puts add(1).(2).(3)
# 6
```

If you're learning Ruby, this kind of metaprogramming trick isn't what you should concentrate on first. It's cool to know that we can do this, it doesn't mean that we should, though.

Comment: Ok, you win. xd But you know this is evil. Maybe if we could make it work with refinements...

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite do what you are trying to do. The reason is that you have to return something and that something can't change based on whether you are going to continue the chain or not.

Note that some Rails objects give you the illusion that you can in the REPL (irb, pry), but they actually just redefine `#inspect`, which is called upon visualisation by said REPL.

---

Instead you can do something very similar, which has an even better interface IMO:

```
def add(starting_number)
  sum = starting_number

  accumulator = proc do |next_number|
    if next_number
      sum += next_number
      accumulator
    else
      sum
    end
  end
end

add(1)                # => #<Proc:0x007fb8ae20e860@(pry):4>
add(1).(2)            # => #<Proc:0x007fb8ae4894f0@(pry):4>

add(1).()             # => 1
add(1).(2).()         # => 3
add(1).(2).(3).(4).() # => 10
```

Comment: `You can't quite do what you are trying to do.` [citation needed]