# How does the Add method work?

Tags: ruby

The code snippet is from: [Adding numbers in succession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330033/adding-numbers-in-succession)

I don't understand how defining the method call(n) makes method add(n) work.

I also don't understand how the "." when calling the add(1).(2) works.

```
class Integer
  def call(n)
    self + n
  end
end

def add(n)
  n
end

puts add(1)
#=> 1
puts add(1).(2)
#=> 3
puts add(1).(2).(3)
#=> 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add` is simply the identity method. Its behavior *does not change* by the introduction of `call`. `call` is a new method being defined on the `Integer` class. Reopening a built-in class like this is often called monkey-patching, and it actually does change the original class. We're not making a new class here.

So the *actual* internal integer class now has a `call` method. Ruby has special syntax with regard to `call`. Putting `.( ... )` will desugar to `.call( ... )`. So

```
add(1).(2)
```

is equivalent to

```
add(1).call(2)
```

but also, the `add` method itself is just fluff. With the `call` method defined on `Integer`, all of the following produce the same result.

```
add(1).(2).(3)
add(1).call(2).call(3)
1.(2).(3)
1.call(2).call(3)
```